Puppeteer doesn't load dynamic content (.setContent method)
I am using Puppeteer to take screenshots of the given HTML, the problem is that the setContent method does not load all the resources that are dynamically loaded (in my opinion). As a result, the screenshot does not contain some images.
This htmlData is simply an html document in a string. I haven't found any similar topics. In my case, the problem is related to the fact that there are scripts in HTML that load dynamic resources from external sources and control the behavior of the page.  The html structure may vary.  I'm looking for a way to load these things as it happens in the page.goto method.  I use the setContent method because I need to modify the HTML and visualize to clients using a screenshot what their website would look like after the changes.
Since the html is very large, I will provide the website address and the way I parse the code. I chose a completely random website where the described problem occurs.
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import puppeteer, { KnownDevices } from 'puppeteer';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const DOMParser = new JSDOM().window.DOMParser;

const OMIT_SCRIPTS = {
  id: ['chat-button-container'],
  src: ['klaviyo'],
  class: ['boomerang', 'analytics'],
  text: ['klaviyo', 'boomerang', 'analytics'],
};

const STYLES_SELECTOR = 'link[rel="stylesheet"]';
const FONTS_SELECTOR = 'link[type*="font"]';
const SCRIPTS_SELECTOR = 'script';
const ABSOLUTE_PATH_PREFIX = 'https://';
const RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX = '//';
const CDN_PREFIX = 'cdn';

const PATH_PREFIX_MAP = {
  [`"${RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX}`]: `"${ABSOLUTE_PATH_PREFIX}`,
  [`, ${RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX}`]: `, ${ABSOLUTE_PATH_PREFIX}`,
  [`,${RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX}`]: `,${ABSOLUTE_PATH_PREFIX}`,
  [`${RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX}${CDN_PREFIX}`]: `${ABSOLUTE_PATH_PREFIX}${CDN_PREFIX}`,
};

const PATH_PREFIX_REGEX = new RegExp(
  Object.keys(PATH_PREFIX_MAP).join('|'),
  'g'
);

const findHeader = (document) => {
  return (
    document.querySelector('[id$="__header"]') ||
    document.querySelector('header') ||
    document.querySelector('[id$="header"]') ||
    null
  );
};

const fixMarkupLinks = (content) =>
  content.replace(PATH_PREFIX_REGEX, (matched) => PATH_PREFIX_MAP[matched]);

const fixUrl = (content) => {
  if (content.startsWith(RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX)) {
    return content.replace(RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX, ABSOLUTE_PATH_PREFIX);
  }
  return content;
};

const getGlobalStyles = (htmlDocument) => {
  let css = '';
  const styletags = htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('style');
  for (const styletag of styletags) {
    css += styletag.innerHTML;
  }
  for (const styleSheet of htmlDocument.styleSheets) {
    for (const rule of styleSheet.cssRules) {
      css += rule.cssText;
    }
  }
  css = fixMarkupLinks(css);
  return css;
};

const getScripts = (htmlDocument) => {
  const scripts = htmlDocument.querySelectorAll(SCRIPTS_SELECTOR);
  const filtered = Array.from(scripts)
    .filter((x) => !OMIT_SCRIPTS.id.includes((x as any).id))
    .filter((x) => !OMIT_SCRIPTS.src.some((s) => (x as any).src.includes(s)))
    .filter(
      (x) => !OMIT_SCRIPTS.class.some((c) => (x as any).className.includes(c))
    )
    .filter(
      (x) => !OMIT_SCRIPTS.text.some((t) => (x as any).textContent.includes(t))
    );

  for (const script of scripts) {
    if (script.src) {
      script.src = fixUrl(script.src);
    }
  }
  return filtered;
};

const getStylesheets = (htmlDocument) => {
  const styles = htmlDocument.querySelectorAll(STYLES_SELECTOR);
  const fonts = htmlDocument.querySelectorAll(FONTS_SELECTOR);

  for (const style of styles) {
    style.href = fixUrl(style.href);
  }

  for (const font of fonts) {
    font.href = fixUrl(font.href);
  }
  return [...styles, ...fonts];
};

const removeHeaderFromDocument = (html) => {
  const dom = new JSDOM(html);
  const { document } = dom.window;

  const header = findHeader(document);
  if (header) {
    header.parentNode?.removeChild(header);
    const announcementElements = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('[id*="announcement"]')
    );
    for (const element of announcementElements) {
      element.parentNode?.removeChild(element);
    }
  }
  return dom.serialize();
};

const parseHtml = (textContent: string) =>
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(textContent, 'text/html');

const fetchUrlContent = async (url) => {
  try {
    const content = await fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((resText) => resText);
    return content;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
};

const fetchFullPage = async (url: string) => {
  const textContent = await fetchUrlContent(url);
  if (!textContent) {
    return null;
  }
  const html = parseHtml(textContent);
  const globalStyles = getGlobalStyles(html);
  const externalStyles = getStylesheets(html);
  const scripts = getScripts(html);
  return { html, globalStyles, externalStyles, scripts };
};

export const getMobileShopPreviewScreenshotTest = async (shopUrl: string) => {
  try {
    let htmlData: any = await fetchFullPage(shopUrl);

    if (htmlData?.html) {
      const dom = new JSDOM(htmlData.html.documentElement.outerHTML);
      const htmlString = dom.serialize();
      htmlData = htmlString;
    }

    if (htmlData) {
      htmlData = removeHeaderFromDocument(htmlData);
    }

    console.log('Making page screenshot...');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
      await dialog.dismiss();
    });

    page.on('console', (consoleObj) => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

    const iPhone = KnownDevices['iPhone 13 Pro'];
    await page.emulate(iPhone);

    // @ts-ignore
    await page.setContent(htmlData, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
      timeout: 60000,
    });

    const screenshotBuffer = await page.screenshot();
    await browser.close();

    console.log('Saving screenshot...');
    const parsedUrl = new URL(shopUrl);
    const hostname = parsedUrl.hostname;
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `${hostname}.png`);

    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, screenshotBuffer);

    console.log(`Screenshot saved at ${filePath}`);
    return filePath;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Generating mobile preview screenshot failed, ${error}`);
    throw new Error(`Cannot generate mobile preview screenshot for ${shopUrl}`);
  }
};

await getMobileShopPreviewScreenshotTest('https://www.beachbunnyswimwear.com/');

Code description:
The code above downloads a webpage, processes its HTML content, strips off some of its elements (like header), and converts relative URLs into absolute ones. Later, using Puppeteer, it emulates an iPhone 13 Pro and takes a screenshot. Finally, it saves the screenshot into a local directory. Since it should be just a minimal example, I have omitted some things that I normally add to these websites (header replacement for example), it doesn't matter, the behaviour of the script is the same in both cases.

What's htmlData? Any resources need to be inlined into the HTML or hosted by a server. See Playwright - Can't access local files using file:// in an img tag

This question is similar to: Playwright - Can't access local files using file:// in an img tag. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

htmlData is simply an html document in a string.  In my case, the problem is related to the fact that there are scripts in HTML that load dynamic resources from external sources and control the behavior of the page.  The html structure may vary.  I'm looking for a way to load these things as it happens in the page.goto method.  I use the setContent method because I need to modify the HTML and visualize to clients using a screenshot what their website would look like after the changes.

I know it's an HTML document in a string, but my question is: what specific HTML document is in that string? I need a specific page to be able to reproduce and understand your problem. setContent runs scripts the same as goto, but unlike goto, there's no guarantee there's a server running, so you'll need to run one to host any resources, as mentioned above and in the link. Did you look at the duplicate suggestion?

Thanks, but that's hard to read. Can you [edit] that into the post? I need something I can copy-paste and run to see the problem easily, without guesswork. Why are you putting the string through JSDOM here though? A random third party website probably won't work, because the server won't serve assets to it due to CORS. But that's not a problem you'd have on your own template running on your own server. Make sure when you do pick a site, that it actually behaves like your real use case.

I edited the original post. I use a string because I make some changes along the way, but it does not affect the loading of the content. Besides, I use cloud functions.

Whatever you use, I need to see it as a [mcve] to be able to help. You're claiming setContent doesn't load resources when it does, so you're clearly doing something incorrectly, but it's not clear what based on these incomplete snippets.

I've edited the original post.

OK, thanks. There's plenty of code now, but I have no context for why it all exists (whatever your use case is seems highly unusual, so you should explain it clearly--what is this code supposed to achieve?). It isn't minimal, and I still can't run it because there are calls like getStorage that I don't have. Please remove anything irrelevant to the problem.

Hey, I have provided a minimal example of the code. Now you should be able to run it.

All right, it's complete but it's still a ton of complicated code and I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Going all the way back to the beginning of the conversation, you're requesting resources like images but if you're requesting those from a server that doesn't want to serve to you, it's not going to work. This isn't related to setContent, it's just any website that tries to make a CORS request. Does this make sense? A minimal reprex of the behavior is simple HTML you can run in any browser, without Puppeteer: <img src="link-to-image-blocked-by-cors.jpg">.

https://www.beachbunnyswimwear.com/ (or any other website) is under absolutely no obligation to serve any of its resources to your origin, and probably shouldn't, if they know what they're doing. If you want a complete screenshot of that (or any) site, navigate to it with goto and take the screenshot--much easier than hundreds of lines of code trying to shoehorn it into making it work on your origin.

Ok, I understand, it's a pity, but I can't use the goto method because I wouldn't be able to paste my changes this way. Moreover, as I said, this would happen with the consent of the client, who would be presented with a simulation of changes as a quick visualization upon request. This page is just an example of a store.

Thanks, now I understand how it works :(

Can you navigate to that page, apply the changes on that origin and screenshot it?
